# Installing Magento 2 Installation Problem in Magento_ConfigurableSampleData

Tags: magento2, installation

we download magento 2 and start the setup process.we configure the database,php and all.At the end of the  Install process it stops at 67%.There is no error found in log.we wait more than 2 hours but there is no change in the installation progress.

The installation stuck the module :Magento_ConfigurableSampleData

[image: install.PNG]

Could you please help us,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue is that your `PHP/nginx/Varnish` settings are not configured properly to run the Magento installation process.

The installation process requires the following settings:

All web servers and Varnish

Locate your `php.ini` using a `phpinfo.php` file.
As a user with root privileges, open php.ini in a text editor.
Locate the `max_execution_time` setting.
Change its value to **18000**.
Save your changes to `php.ini` and exit the text editor.
**Restart Apache:**

```
CentOS: service httpd restart
Ubuntu: service apache2 restart
```

If you use **nginx** or **Varnish**, continue with the following sections.

nginx only

If you use nginx, use our included nginx.conf.sample or add a timeout settings in the nginx host configuration file to the location ~ `^/setup/index.php` section as follows:

```
location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
    .....................
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
}
```

**Restart nginx**: `service nginx restart`

**Varnish only**

If you use Varnish, edit `default.vcl` and add a timeout limit value to the backend stanza as follows:

```
backend default {
.....................
      .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}
```

**Restart Varnish:**

```
service varnish restart
```

Those instructions are from the official Magento 2 Developer Documentation:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_70pct.html

Comment: if it works, please upvote and mark it as correct.

Comment: sure bro, thankyou